# Build content block in Prawn?

Tags: prawn

This seems to be easy but I can't find a solution.  I have a table like this:

```
table([["cell 1","cell 2","cell 3" ]]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
content = block do
 text 'Location'
 text 'Location2'
end

table([[content,"cell 2","cell 3" ]]
```

Can you do this in Prawn?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with a custom table cell implemetnation. However, as far as I know this is not possible with `prawn-table` itself.

The problem with what you want is that the auto-sizing of a cell gets much more complicated if complex content is allowed in a table cell.